# Kotlin coroutines - start another task if after some time the first one doesn't finish

Tags: android, database, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Kotlin coroutines to get data from the server, I am passing the deferred over to other functions. In case the server doesn't give an answer in 2000 ms I would like to retrive the object from a local Room DB (if it exists in a local database), but if I finally receive data from the server I would like to save in in a local DB for future calls. How can I acheive that? I thought about using withTimeout, but in this situation, there is no waiting for a response from the server after timeout.

```
override fun getDocument(): Deferred<Document> {
    return GlobalScope.async {
        withTimeoutOrNull(timeOut) {
            serverC.getDocument().await()
        } ?: dbC.getDocument().await()
    }
}
```

An idea I came up with:

```
fun getDocuments(): Deferred<Array<Document>> {
    return GlobalScope.async {
        val s = serverC.getDocuments()
        delay(2000)
        if (!s.isCompleted) {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                dbC.addDocuments(s.await())
            }
            val fromDb = dbC.getDocuments().await()
            if (fromDb != null) {
                fromDb
            } else {
                s.await()
            }
        } else {
            s.await()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the `select` expression from the `kotlinx.coroutines` library.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/select-expression.html

```
fun CoroutineScope.getDocumentsRemote(): Deferred<List<Document>>
fun CoroutineScope.getDocumentsLocal(): Deferred<List<Document>>

@UseExperimental(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun CoroutineScope.getDocuments(): Deferred<List<Document>> = async {
    supervisorScope {
        val documents = getDocumentsRemote()
        select<List<Document>> {
            onTimeout(100) {
                documents.cancel()
                getDocumentsLocal().await()
            }
            documents.onAwait {
                it

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The select expression resumes either with the `onAwait` signal from the network or with the timeout. We return the local data in that case.

You may want to load documents in chunks as well, for that `Channel`s may help too
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html

And lastly, we use an Experimental API of kotlinx.coroutines in the example, the function `onTimeout` may change in the future versions of the library

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, after 100 ms, the server job is cancelled. What I would like to achieve in this situation is returning the local value, but also save the data from the server in the database when it arrives.

Comment: I would recommend making both jobs contribute to the `Channel<Document>`, so that it will deliver results instantly to the requestor, otherwise, the callee will not have results after 2 seconds if server request runs slower that that